# how to save android Application logs into Device storage via JAVA Program

Tags: android, debugging, logging, logcat

I need to get my developed Android app logs. I seen we can do it using adb and android studio, but i want to save logs into device memory for app event track as i can not use PC all time. I am using log.i, log.d, log.e in my coding.

I searched on internet and found some methods but none of them able to create all events logs into file while using android studio logcat i am getting all the event logs of my App.

**AndroidManifes.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Main.java**

> ```
> onCreate(){
> if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
>
>     File appDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "TP3");
>     Log.d("dbKaps", "App directory created ");
>     File logDirectory = new File(appDirectory + "/logs");
>     Log.d("dbKaps", "Log directory created ");
>     File logFile = new File(logDirectory, "logcat_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt");
>     Log.d("dbKaps", "logcat TXT file created ");
>
>     // create app folder
>     if (!appDirectory.exists()) {
>         appDirectory.mkdir();
>         Log.d("dbKaps", "App Directory already exists ");
>     }
>
>     // create log folder
>     if (!logDirectory.exists()) {
>         logDirectory.mkdir();
>         Log.d("dbKaps", "Log Directory already exists ");
>     }
>
>     // clear the previous logcat and then write the new one to the file
>     try {
>         Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
>         process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile);
>         Log.d("dbKaps", "new logcat started ");
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
>
>
> } else if (isExternalStorageReadable()) {
>     // only readable
> } else {
>     // not accessible
> }
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
>     String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
>     if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ) {
>         Log.i("dbKaps", "Storage writable permission granted ");
>         return true;
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
>     String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
>     if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ||
>             Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals( state ) ) {
>         Log.i("dbKaps", "Storage readable permission granted only ");
>         return true;
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ```

**OUTPUT:**

I am getting limited event logs into lofile.

> 08-11 22:56:44.779 I/BufferQueueConsumer(30620): [](id:779c00000000,api:0,p:-1,c:30620) connect: controlledByApp=false
>
> 08-11 22:56:44.781 I/BLASTBufferQueue(30620): [ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#0] constructor()
>
> 08-11 22:56:44.792 E/GED     (30620): Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
>
> 08-11 22:56:44.794 D/hw-ProcessState(30620): Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
>
> 08-11 22:56:44.814 I/BufferQueueProducer(30620): [ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#0(BLAST Consumer)0](id:779c00000000,api:1,p:30620,c:30620) connect: api=1 producerControlledByApp=true
>
> 08-11 22:56:44.824 E/ion     (30620): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
>
> 08-11 22:56:44.948 E/OpenGLRenderer(30620): fbcNotifyFrameComplete error: undefined symbol: fbcNotifyFrameComplete
>
> 08-11 22:56:44.948 E/OpenGLRenderer(30620): fbcNotifyNoRender error: undefined symbol: fbcNotifyNoRender